# (Python) Getting errors when calculating range of dates

Tags: python, datetime

I've tried following examples such as https://www.pythonprogramming.in/get-range-of-dates-between-specified-start-and-end-date.html and [Python generating a list of dates between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59882714/python-generating-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates/59882807) with various slightly different versions of the same code:

```
import datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta

def daterange():
    while True:
        d1 = input("Please enter in the earliest date: ")
        check1 = d1.replace("-","")
        if check1.isdigit:
            d2 = input("Please enter in the latest date: ")
            check2 = d2.replace("-","")
            if check2.isdigit:
                date1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d1, '%d-%m-%Y').strftime('%Y,%m,%d')## this is to convert my intended input format
                date2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d2, '%d-%m-%Y').strftime('%Y,%m,%d')## this is to convert my intended input format
                print (date1)
                print (date2)
                dd = [date1 + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range (0,(date2-date1).days)]
                print (dd)
                return                    
            else:
                print("That was an invalid date")
        else:
            print("That was an invalid date")
```

And I'm getting the same error where it cannot do a subtraction in `date2-date1`:
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`
Can anyone explain why and provide a solution?

Comment: Make sure you are aware of which data type you (have to) use where in the code; string ≠ datetime object. `strftime` formats date(time) objects to string. You cannot do timedelta arithmetic with strings. remove `.strftime('%Y,%m,%d')`.

Comment: Can timedelta understand if the format is in ('%d-%m-%Y') format?

Comment: No. datetime or timedelta objects have no *format*, only the string representation of date/time/timedelta has a certain format.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a timedelta to a str, which is what you are doing. This line: `date1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d1, '%d-%m-%Y').strftime('%Y,%m,%d')` creates a datetime obj, and then converts it back to str.

Change your code like so and it will work:

```
import datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta


def daterange():
    while True:
        d1 = input("Please enter in the earliest date: ")
        check1 = d1.replace("-","")
        if check1.isdigit:
            d2 = input("Please enter in the latest date: ")
            check2 = d2.replace("-","")
            if check2.isdigit:
                date1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d1, '%d-%m-%Y')
                date2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d2, '%d-%m-%Y')
                print (date1)
                print (date2)
                dd = [date1 + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range (0,(date2-date1).days)]
                print (dd)
                return
            else:
                print("That was an invalid date")
        else:
            print("That was an invalid date")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    daterange()
```