# How to search value in object list between two dates python

Tags: python

I have code in python like this :

```
class Market(object):
    def __init__(self, name, date):
        self.name = name
        self.date = date

marketValue = []
marketValue.append(Market("Knife", "2021-07-21"))
marketValue.append(Market("Pan", "2021-07-22"))
marketValue.append(Market("Glass", "2021-07-23"))

for obj in marketValue:
    print(obj.name + " - " + obj.date)
```

With output :

```
Knife - 2021-07-21
Pan - 2021-07-22
Glass - 2021-07-23
```

Can i filter or search in my object list between two dates? For example startDate = '2021-07-21' , endDate = '2021-07-22'. Then And the result is like this, according to search :

```
Knife - 2021-07-21
Pan - 2021-07-22
```

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python generating a list of dates between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59882714/python-generating-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates)

Comment: Take a look at [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html): [example](https://akuiper.com/console/yRvl3ncWlLNE)

Comment: Is it ok, if you want to use other modules?

Comment: sure sir, tell me @PCM

Comment: I think the problem is different, it makes me confused (leaf_yakitori) ,
thx for ur reference (Psidom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use datetime module to generate a range of dates -

```
marketValue = []
marketValue.append(Market("Knife", "2021-07-21"))
marketValue.append(Market("Pan", "2021-07-22"))
marketValue.append(Market("Glass", "2021-07-23"))

startDate = '2021-07-21'
endDate = '2021-07-22'

sd = datetime.date(2021,7,21)

ed = datetime.date(2021,7,22)

dates = [(str(sd.year) + '-0' + str(sd.month)+'-') + str(i) for i in range(sd.day,ed.day+1)]
print(dates)

for obj in marketValue:
    if obj.date in dates:
        print(obj.name + " - " + obj.date)
```

I hope you get this right!